# To add column with title "total" by javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cell, addition

I am trying to add a column by using for-loop.
I do not get any error but nothing happened.
Can someone help with this? 
Thanks in advance.

```
 function add(){
    //att läsa hela tabell
    var tabell = document.getElementById("c");
    //att läsa taggan tr
    var rader = tabell.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    //att läsa alla rader i tabellen
    for(var i = 0; i < rader.length; i++){
        //medan alla rader läsas upp skapar td element
        var nyCell = document.createElement("td");
        //indikerar nyCell i alla rader
        rader[i].appendChild(nyCell);

        var nyRad = document.createElement("tr");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in console? The code itself looks fine to me, as long as `rader.length` is more than 0.

Comment: Is element with `id` = "c" a table? If so, does this table have any rows? Please add the relevant `HTML` as an example in your post

Comment: nyCell is empty so will only show up if you inpect it in the console

Comment: @mplungjan Well, unless the table already has formatting that would make it display.

Comment: sure.. I tried with `td { border: 1px solid black }` and it does show a tiny cell

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53670659/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] with relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: there is no error in console.. @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: I found out how to make this work, tks for your comment! @RyanWilson

Comment: @rewe You're welcome. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works given a table like below

NOTE: I CALL the function `add()` at some stage. It has to be after the table exists.

```js
function add() {
  //att läsa hela tabell
  var tabell = document.getElementById("c");
  //att läsa taggan tr
  var rader = tabell.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  //att läsa alla rader i tabellen
  for (var i = 0; i < rader.length; i++) {
    //medan alla rader läsas upp skapar td element
    var nyCell = document.createElement("td");
    //indikerar nyCell i alla rader
    nyCell.innerHTML = "Hejsan";
    rader[i].appendChild(nyCell);
  }
}
add()
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table id="c">
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

I believe you actually mean this

```js
function add() {
  /*att skapa th som står summa*/
  var tableHeadRow = document.querySelector("#c thead tr"); //ONE row

    var nyTh = document.createElement("th");
    nyTh.innerHTML = "Summa";
    tableHeadRow.appendChild(nyTh);

  var tableBody = document.querySelector("#c tbody");
  var tableBodyRows = tableBody.querySelectorAll("tr"); // ALL rows
  //att läsa alla rader i tabellen
  for (var i = 0; i < tableBodyRows.length; i++) {
    //medan alla rader läsas upp skapar td element
    var nyCell = document.createElement("td");
    //indikerar nyCell i alla rader
    nyCell.innerHTML = "";
    tableBodyRows[i].appendChild(nyCell); // add ONE cell to the end of each row
  }

  /*to add new row*/
  var nyRad = document.createElement("tr");
  var nyCell1 = document.createElement("td");
  var nyCell2 = document.createElement("td");
  var nyCell3 = document.createElement("td");
  var nyCell4 = document.createElement("td");
  nyCell4.innerText="Total";
  nyRad.appendChild(nyCell1);
  nyRad.appendChild(nyCell2);
  nyRad.appendChild(nyCell3);
  nyRad.appendChild(nyCell4);
  tableBody.appendChild(nyRad);
}
add()
```

```css
    td {
      border: 1px solid black
    }
```

```html
<table id="c">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh Thank you Mplugjan! 

However im wondering why you put add() at last as well?

Comment: It has to be executed. If you do not execute it nothing will happen - as you seem to have found out

Comment: So for example when the page loads: `window.addEventListener("load",add)` or just `add()` if called after the table exists, as in a `<script>add()</script>` just before the `</body>`

Comment: Ok, Thank you @mplungjan ! One more question, if I want to add to only <th> and add empty cell to each row, should I write separately like under?

    for (var i = 0; i < rader.length; i++) {
    
    var nyTh = document.createElement("th");
    var nyCell = document.createElement("td");
   
    nyTh.innerHTML = "Summa";
    
   
    rader[i].appendChild(nyTh);
  }
}
add()

Comment: Ok, Thank you @mplungjan !

Comment: th are instead of td. They are children of TRs

Comment: Please see update. You need to read up on [TABLE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan and tks for the link! I now could add a new th and empty cell to each row. Could you please see if I am writing correct to add a new row at last if you have time?

Comment: Please see last example which I believe is doing what you want

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan ! This is exactly what I meant. And thank you for the comments! It is so helpful!